# How to say "cognitive shift" in Russian?

Tags: терминология

It’s a wide used term and has its own article in wiki: [Cognitive shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_shift).

In Russian, I failed to find something better than this awkward "изменения в осознании".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In more colloquial terms it could be translated as `Сдвиг по фазе`, but that is closer to insanity, not just any shift in any direction. I think it could be translated literally - `Когнитивный сдвиг`. There are lots of adopted words in russian nowadays. You may want to search some professional psychologic literature for a more precise translation

Comment: Here's a Russian version of a book where the term is translated as когнитивный сдвиг. One of its authors, Aaron T. Beck is often referred to as the person who introduced that term. http://www.goldbiblioteca.ru/online_psihologiya/online_psistr/5.php

Comment: In non-academic contexts, it could be translated as "трансформация сознания". It’s not the same as cognitive shift but more popular and general term